# SQL Server 2008 Group Based on a Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm struggling to find if this is possible to use SQL Server 2008 to assign a sequence without having to use cursors. Let's say I have the following table which defines a driver's driving route going from one location to another (null means he is going from home):

```
RouteID   SourceLocationID   DestinationLocationID  DriverID   Created   Updated
-------  ----------------   ---------------------   --------   -------   -------
 1        NULL               219                     1         10:20     10:23  
 2        219                266                     1         10:21     10:24
 3        266                NULL                    1         10:22     10:25
 4        NULL               54                      2         10:23     10:26
 5        54                 NULL                    2         10:24     10:27
 6        NULL               300                     1         10:25     10:28
 7        300                NULL                    1         10:26     10:29
```

I want to group the records between the rows where sourceLID is NULL and the destinationLID is null, so I get the following (generating a sequence number for each grouping set):

```
DriverID  DestinationLocationID   TripNumber
--------  ---------------------   ----------
 1         219                     1 (his first trip)
 1         266                     1
 1         300                     2 (his second trip)
 2         54                      1
```

Is there a way I could use GROUP BY here rather than cursors?

Comment: A good question with a great answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a quick try:

```
with cte as
( select DestinationLocationID
       , DriverID
       , tripid = row_number() 
         over ( partition by driverid 
                order by DestinationLocationID)  
    from table1 
    where sourcelocationid is NULL
  UNION ALL
  select table1.DestinationLocationID
       , table1.DriverID
       , cte.tripid 
    from table1 
    join cte on  table1.SourceLocationID=cte.DestinationLocationID
             and table1.DriverID=cte.DriverID
    where cte.DestinationLocationID is not null
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: I get this error 'Recursive common table expression 'cte' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.'

Comment: @AshesToAshes try again please?,

Comment: IMHO,Query is not giving correct output as well as it not efficient at all.Row_number() with partition inside recursive CTE ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select driverid, destinationlocationid, count(destinationlocationid) from 
(
select driverid, destinationlocationid from table1 where sourcelocationid is NULL
union all
select driverid, sourcelocationid from table1 where destinationlocationid is NULL
)A group by driverid, destinationlocationid
```

Comment: Just tried this and it does not correctly iterate up the sequence for a given driver.

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated sub-query to count previous trips, plus 1 to get this trip number.

```
select DriverID,
       DestinationLocationID,
       (select count(*) + 1
        from routes t2
        where t1.DriverID = t2.DriverID
        and t1.RouteID > t2.RouteID
        and DestinationLocationID IS NULL) as TripNumber
from routes t1
where DestinationLocationID IS NOT NULL
order by DriverID, DestinationLocationID;
```

Executes like this:

```
SQL>select DriverID,
SQL&       DestinationLocationID,
SQL&       (select count(*) + 1
SQL&        from routes t2
SQL&        where t1.DriverID = t2.DriverID
SQL&        and t1.RouteID > t2.RouteID
SQL&        and DestinationLocationID IS NULL) as TripNumber
SQL&from routes t1
SQL&where DestinationLocationID IS NOT NULL
SQL&order by DriverID, DestinationLocationID;
   DriverID DestinationLocationID   TripNumber
=========== ===================== ============
          1                   219            1
          1                   266            1
          1                   300            2
          2                    54            1

                  4 rows found
```

Comment: This does not seem to work either as it's assigning different TripNumber's within the same trip. It needs to iterate for each grouping set.

Comment: @AshesToAshes, right... Didn't read carefully enough... Will edit. Thanks!

Comment: No it still gives weird results :(

Comment: Now it's supposed to work. Had to create table and test, noticed I'd turned sub-query > condition wrong way...

Comment: i like the query,if you replace your sub query with  isnull((select  1+1
        from @t t2
        where t1.DriverID = t2.DriverID
        and t1.RouteID > t2.RouteID
        and DestinationLocationID IS NULL),1) as TripNumber .Then this way you can remove count(*),hence more efficient.But I am not so sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Declare @t table(RouteID int, SourceLocationID int,DestinationLocationID int
,DriverID int,Created time, Updated time)
insert into @t
 values(1, NULL, 219, 1, '10:20','10:23'),  
 (2 ,219,266, 1, '10:21','10:24'), 
 (3,266, NULL, 1, '10:22','10:25'), 
 (4, NULL, 54, 2, '10:23','10:26'), 
 (5,54, NULL, 2, '10:24','10:27'), 
 (6,NULL,300, 1, '10:25','10:28'), 
 (7,300,NULL, 1, '10:26','10:29')

;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY DriverID ORDER BY Created
            ) RN
    FROM @t
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,1 TripNumber
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT A.*
        ,CASE 
            WHEN A.SourceLocationID IS NULL
                THEN B.TripNumber + 1
            ELSE B.TripNumber
            END
    FROM CTE1 B
    INNER JOIN CTE A ON B.DriverID = A.DriverID
    WHERE A.RN > B.RN
    )
SELECT DISTINCT DestinationLocationID
    ,DriverID
    ,TripNumber
FROM CTE1
WHERE DestinationLocationID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY DriverID
```